# is it possible to change font build by svg images color in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have font build by group of images to save writing shape, so this font is unicode and each unicode character presents a single word, until now every thing working fine with font coloring in the application.

after we update the font to contain static colors (inside the font ttf) the issue appear that I cannot change the uncolored parts of the glyph.
please see the attached image that contain four characters the first two was colored correctly (blue) but the others were not.

is there any suggestion to replace the black color only in the character with white color to be used in the Dark mode ?

[image]

Comment: Could you share what have you tried ? maybe some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research on that this was a capability from the font itself, I asked the font creator to support that in order to achieve what I need her.

Also I tried many ways in iOS to do that it seems no solution from mobile side